# Get the value of a dropdown inside the view after select option is closed

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, modal-dialog, dropdown

I have a modal that pops out and displays a few variables. After displaying these variables, it has a dropdown with a few options. I'm trying to get it so that what value they choose inside the dropdown is able to be converted to a tag so i can use it in an operation after they choose it. After they choose the dropdown, let's say they choose 10x, I need to pull the value of 10 after they choose it, to use it to multiply the `$netincome` tag i have inside. Here's my code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
      <?php echo form_open(base_url('admin/work/start_working'), 'class="form-container"'); ?>
      
       <div class="form-group has-feedback">
             <input type="text" name="basin" id="basin" value="<?= $netincome; ?> <?= $ress; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="<?= $netincome; ?>" > <center>&</center> <input type="text" name="basin" id="basin" value="<?= $netincome2; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Cash: <?= $netincome2; ?>" >
        </div>
      <br>
     <div class="form-group has-feedback">
      <select id="times" name="times" class="browser-default custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3">
      <option value="1" selected>1x</option>
      <option value="2">2x</option>
      <option value="5">5x</option>
      <option value="10">10x</option>
      <option value="20">20x</option>
      <option value="40">40x</option>
      <option value="42">42x</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <?php
    $amt = WHERE I'M TRYING TO PULL THE OPTION VALUE ABOVE;
    ?>
    <?php 
      $finalamt = $netincome * $amt;
      ?>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
             <input type="text" name="netin" id="netin" value="<?= $finalamt; ?> <?= $ress; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="<?= $finalamt; ?>" > <center>&</center> <input type="text" name="basin" id="basin" value="<?= $netincome2; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Cash: <?= $netincome2; ?>" >
        </div>
    </div>
```

Under the dropdown is the $amt tag and under that is where i multiply $netincome * $amt. I just can't seem to capture the option value. I'm not very fluent in Javascript so I'm not sure if that will be a better option here.

Comment: So the question is: how to get the value from the selected option inside the ````select```` tag? The modal pops up and after a "Confirm" click it disappears? Do I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the value using PHP then you have to submit form in order to get value using

```
$_POST['times'];
```

or if you want it without pageload then you can use Jquery

```
var times = $('#times').val();
```

and you can multiple it in jquery and show it somewhere the some of that like:

```
var total = times * 10;
```

to show this total somewhere like in an element with id abc:

```
$('#abc').html(total);
```

Your final code will be:

```
<div id="abc"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#times').change(function(){
var times = $('#times').val();
var total = times * 10;
$('#abc').html(total);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Again, I'm still new to JavaScript, So I added those to the modal script, ``` var times = $('#times').val();

var total = times * val();

$('#finalamount').html(total); 
```

Now how do i call on this inside the div tags? I understand the time connects to the times in the dropdown, and pulls value, but how do i connect it to the div inside the table and get that value? Inside you put multiplying by ten if selected ten, which im guessing thats the val() it pulls. How do i display that total inside the textbox in the div underneath the table?

Answer (score 0):

write a event listener for select onchange event on submit the form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#times').change(function(){
// Call submit() method on <form id='myform'>
$('#myform').submit();
});
});
```

then get date with post method $_POST['times'] on server side

Answer (score 0):

Your final code will be:

```
<div id="abc"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#times').change(function(){
var times = $('#times').val();
var total = times * 10;
$('#abc').html(total);
});
});
</script
```

> 